# ISessionStore Implementation Cannot resolve scoped service from root provider in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to implement session storing in the database is ASP.net, to do this I implemented Isession store to interact with the db and store the sessions. Then I called addScope in the startup.cs and injected in all my controllers.

However when I try to run the app I the error "{"Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.ISessionStore' from root provider."}".

I'm not sure why this is as I have injected it in all the controllers, which is what I thought I was supposed to do and all the code looks correct to me. Been stuck on this all day, any guidance on the proper way to set this up and why it would be throwing this error is greatly appreciated.

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace IdentityByExamples
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Cookie.Name = "MySessionCookie";
            });

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opts =>
                opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(opt =>
            {
                opt.Password.RequiredLength = 7;
                opt.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                opt.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;

                opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

                opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;

                opt.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
                opt.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
                opt.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
            })
             .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
             .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


            services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(opt =>
               opt.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2));

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle("google", opt =>
                {
                    var googleAuth = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

                    opt.ClientId = googleAuth["ClientId"];
                    opt.ClientSecret = googleAuth["ClientSecret"];
                    opt.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                });


            services.AddScoped<ISessionStore, SQLServersSessionStore>();

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));


            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Controller

```
namespace IdentityByExamples.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<AccountController> _logger;
        private readonly ISessionStore _sessionStore;


        public AccountController(IMapper mapper, UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager, ILogger<AccountController> logger, ISessionStore sessionStore)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _sessionStore = sessionStore;
        }



        [HttpGet("Test")]
        public String Test()
        {
            var z = 7;
            return "Route Hit";
        }


        [HttpGet("TestAuth")]
        [Authorize]
        public String TestAuth()
        {
            var z = 7;
            return "Route Hit";
        }
```

Isession store implemenation

```
namespace IdentityByExamples.Store
{
    public class SQLServersSessionStore : ISessionStore
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

        public SQLServersSessionStore(AppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }


        public ISession Create(String userId, TimeSpan idleTimeout, TimeSpan absoluteTimeout, Func<bool> tryEstablishSession, bool isNewSessionKey)
        {
            // Generate a new session ID
            string sessionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            // Create a new session entity
            var sessionEntity = new SessionEntity
            {
                SessionId = sessionId,
                UserId =  userId,
                ExpirationDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(idleTimeout)
            };

            // Add the session entity to the database
            _dbContext.Sessions.Add(sessionEntity);
            _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            // Create and return a new Session object
            var session = new Session { Id = sessionId };
            return (ISession)session;
        }
        public async Task CreateAsync(string id, byte[] data, DateTimeOffset expiresAt)
        {
            var session = new SessionEntity
            {
                SessionId = id,
                Data = data,
                ExpirationDate = expiresAt
            };
            await _dbContext.Sessions.AddAsync(session);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task<byte[]> GetAsync(string id)
        {
            var session = await _dbContext.Sessions.FindAsync(id);
            return session?.Data;
        }

        public async Task RemoveAsync(string id)
        {
            var session = await _dbContext.Sessions.FindAsync(id);
            if (session != null)
            {
                _dbContext.Sessions.Remove(session);
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stack Trace

"Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.ISessionStore' from root provider. at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0(RequestDelegate next)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.d__37.MoveNext()\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.d__12.MoveNext()\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)\r\n   at IdentityByExamples.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Me\Downloads\testCangularintegration\IdentityBy\IdentityByExamples\IdentityByExamples\Program.cs:line 16"

with my program cs just being the normal

```
namespace IdentityByExamples
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
// Line 16
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack trace posted now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused by [Scoped Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0#scope-validation) accroding to the stacktrace

If you check the source code of [SessionMiddleWare](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/Session/src/SessionMiddleware.cs),you would found it injected  ISessionStore into the constructor ,which triggered Scoped Validation(If you remove app.UseSession() middleware,the error would disappear)

```
public SessionMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,
        ISessionStore sessionStore,
        IOptions<SessionOptions> options)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(next);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(loggerFactory);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(dataProtectionProvider);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(sessionStore);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(options);

        _next = next;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SessionMiddleware>();
        _dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(nameof(SessionMiddleware));
        _options = options.Value;
        _sessionStore = sessionStore;
    }
```

If you check the services after `services.AddSession()` has been called,you would found another service implemented  ISessionStore interface has been registed,
So just regist your service as Transient follow it

[image]

If you've decided to regist dbcontext as transient,you have to regist dbcontextoption  as transient too,or you'll receive the similar error

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(ServiceLifetime.Transient,ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

When I debug:
[image]

Tried with DbcontextFactory ,it works either:
[image]

Comment: If I do this, then I get a error that the appDbContext isn't scoped correctly. I add that to be scoped but still get error  
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.ISessionStore' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'IdentityByExamples.AppDbContext'.

Comment: I reproduced the error and tried with dbcontextfactory,it works on my side now,you could follow this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor

Comment: did you only add the db context factory in your start up method eg  services.AddDbContextFactory<DbContextFactory>(options => {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection"),
                providerOptions => providerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure());
            }, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);, or did you add this to IServices  interface as well, cause this still throws a error for me. not sure if I implemented it right

Comment: could you show how you implemented the db context factory? I followed the guide but having diffuculty getting it to work

Comment: remove ServiceLifetime.Scoped, it would regist DbcontextFactory as Singleton by default

Comment: You have to avoid inject scoped services into SQLServersSessionStore accroding to the error message,If you regist the dbcontext as transident,it may also resolve your problem,but may cause another error indicates the dbcontext has been disposed somewhere else.

Comment: I tried registering the dbcontext as transient but that didnt work

Comment: where did you add the dbcontext factory code?

Comment: Hi,@nightwolf555,
I've updated my answer,on myside,there were no error thrown now,if you still get  error,please show the error

Comment: Thanks appreciate the update, I was able to get it working one crucial piece to resolve the error was configuring the context like 
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection"),);
            }, ServiceLifetime.Transient, ServiceLifetime.Transient), instead of        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection"));
            }, ServiceLifetime.Transient),